# MySQL exclusions and requirements

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I'd like to convert this problem into a query.
At a guess should be three leftjoin and two select

```
exercises
+-----+---------+
|  id | require | 
+-----+---------+
|  1  |         |
|  2  |    1    |
|  3  |    2    |
|  4  |    3    |
|  5  |         |
|  6  |    5    |
|  7  |         |
+-----+---------+

done
+-----+
|  id |
+-----+
|  1  |
|  2  |
+-----+
```

Having done the exercises one and two, which exercises can I do now?
Solution: 3,5,7

My logical process, step by step:
(all) - SELECT(required - done)-(done)
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) - SELECT((1,2,3,5)-(1,2)) - (1,2)
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) - SELECT(3,5) - (1,2)
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) -(4,6) - (1,2)
(3,5,7)

How to write the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution without subselect

```
SELECT e.id FROM exercises e 
LEFT JOIN done d ON d.id = e.id 
LEFT JOIN done d_req ON d_req.id=e.require 
WHERE (d.id IS NULL AND d_req.id IS NOT NULL) 
         OR (e.require IS NULL AND d.id IS NULL)
```

the `WHERE` can be semplified (distributivity)

```
WHERE d.id IS NULL AND (d_req.id IS NOT NULL OR e.require IS NULL )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select id 
from exercises
where require in (select id from done)
   or require is null
minus
select id from done;
```

Your set is: "Exercises that have de require done or don't have require, execpt those done".

UPDATE: without minus(probably that scared you):

```
select id 
from exercises
where (require in (select id from done)  or require is null)
   and id not in  (select id from done);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing it.

```
SELECT * FROM `exercises`
WHERE `id` NOT IN (SELECT `id` FROM `done`)
AND (
    `require` IS NULL OR
    `require` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `done`)
)
ORDER BY `id`
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working SQL fiddle which shows LIVE output:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0726b/29/0

Also am pasting the query here:

```
SELECT id FROM 
(
  SELECT e1.* FROM exercises e1 
  LEFT JOIN done d1 ON e1.id = d1.id
  WHERE d1.id IS NULL

) AS r1

WHERE r1.`require` IS NULL OR r1.`require` IN (SELECT id from done)
```